# Cassandra JDBC connection string for logstash

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We are recently enabled mtls for cassandra database. After the change our logstash connection got broken, Now we wanted to test with latest cassandra driver but I didn't find the cassandra ssl configuration for logstash.

How to enable ssl for cassandra

`jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:c*://${host}:${port}/${keyspace}"`

Looking for Cassandra string for ssl connections